# Autoadjust Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement fluid grid layout wherein, i donot know the height of the grid columns. It will depend upon the content written which may be dynamic. However, i can fix the width of columns. Sample result is at: ruralolympic.org

I am new to bootstrap and tried to implement all this with html/css only as well as bootstrap.

I have also gone though may online articles here on stackoverflow and googled a lot. I have even visited:  http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/
I found that there are a lot of JQuery based plugins for this work, but I like to have a simple and general code rather than working with a whole new library. Kindly provide me a solution that is simple, html css / bootstrap based. Here is what i have tried:

```
<style>
        .wrapper
        {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .wrapcol1, .wrapcol3
        {
            width: 20%;
            min-width: 20%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .margincol
        {
            width: 10%;
            min-width: 10%;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .wrapcol2
        {
            width: 35%;
            min-width: 35%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .wrapcol1, .margincol, .wrapcol2, .wrapcol3
        {
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .innerwrapper
        {
            vertical-align: top;
            border: 2px solid red;
            text-align: justify;
        }

    </style>
```

The body part is as under:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="innerwrapper">
            <div class="wrapcol1">
                This is Column 1.
            </div>
            <div class="margincol">

            </div>
            <div class="wrapcol2">
                This is Column 2. 
            </div>
            <div class="margincol">

            </div>
            <div class="wrapcol3">
                This is Column 3.
            </div>
            <div class="wrapcol1">
                This is Coumn 4. 
            </div>
            <div class="margincol">

            </div>
            <div class="wrapcol2">
                This is Column 5. 
            </div>
            <div class="margincol">

            </div>
            <div class="wrapcol3">
                This is Column 6. 
            </div>
        </span>         
    </div>
</body>
```

I have shortened the contents to save space here.

Following is the bootstrap code that I used:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>
                    This is box 1.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>
                    This is box 2. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>
                    This is box 3. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
            <!-- Row 2 begins here -->
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>
                    This is Box 4. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>
                    This is Box 5.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>
                    This is Box 6. 
                </p>
            </div>              

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Why you don't want use the columns based grid that bootstrap has to offer?

Comment: Sir, I have no problem in using it. As i mentioned in the description, i tried to use it, but it didnt work. The divs didnt take up empty space to get set automatically. I will add up the code that I wrote in the description now.

Comment: Please don't call me sir. LG is generally used for transformation according to large device. A row is allowed 12 columns in bootstrap and I don't see any reason why it wont work. Let me make a fiddle for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/372ot3yn/1/embedded/#Result

Comment: just click on the results tab.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Just to show what i achieved with the above code (submitted in description), i have uploaded the result here:   [IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2ho92xi.png[/IMG]           The middle column of second row was expected to take up the above blank space and move upwards automatically.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I visited your sample. Its showing a single row. My issue is that i need to have multiple rows, but the successor ones should take up black space left by predecessor columns as can be seend on:   www.ruralolympic.org

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/372ot3yn/10/embedded/#Result This is what you want.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite The solutions you have provided seems working perfect. Just working on it and will post the update and acceptance soon. Thanks for your kind support. Just for the knowledge, did it work because of bootstrap's content-inner? How it behaves / work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/372ot3yn/10/embedded/#Result

**Why this worked?**

Bootstrap is a CSS framework that gives us direct command which has pure css working behind it. Imagine the row being a wrapper class that already has properties and all already done and made such that we wont have problem with responsiveness and all. I suggested you the grid because it'll make it easier to make responsive UI without writing extra css code. You can even do nesting if you wish. Let's say in the last column of the three you want to make separate columns then just use the classes row again in there and you are set to go.

If you wish to explore more just check their original css stylesheet and search for specific classes you are using to check all the properties.

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
<div class="row extracss">
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-inner">
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

          <div>
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

          <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-inner">
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

          <div class="content-inner"> 
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-inner">
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

          <div class="content-inner">
          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

          <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>
                    <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>
                    <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>
                    <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>
                    <div class="content-inner">

         Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content          Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
          </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `float:left;` on your wrapcol div like:

```
.wrapcol1, .margincol, .wrapcol2, .wrapcol3
    {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this didnt work. When I put in varying content in the divs, The divs of second row failed to occupy the blank spaces above it.  Here is the output:   [IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/not2mv.png[/IMG]

Comment: Sorry, This didnt work and i have attached the snapshot above. Even, due to float left, all columns floated to left while i expected them in the center of parent element. So, float left was not a solutions for me at all. Please visit www.ruralolympic.org to see what I am expecting.

Comment: why you try bootstrap grid